# trigger windows key + period with jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dispatchevent

Since Windows 10 there is an integrated emoji collection that can be accessed with a combination [(Windows logo key   + . (period))](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942#:%7E:text=To%20use%20it%3A,The%20emoji%20keyboard%20will%20appear.)

What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to trigger that combination on an element click with either jQuery or pure JS.

I have tried searching to see if someone already has a solution for that, but can't seem to find anything apart from that thread [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) but not sure how to do it.

So, for example, let say that with have this element `<span id="emoji">Open Emoji</span>`, how do we trigger (Windows logo key   + . (period)) on click?

Comment: Don't think you can since Windows will need to capture that event. All the events triggered in JS will stay in the browser en will not get noticed by windows.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you could, you could take command of a user's machine

Comment: uh, thanks!... didn't know that!